# JWT Authentication Error after Deploying to Railway

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have implemented Spring Security with JWT into my application and I am using Angular served by Springboot 3; same origin. However, I am encountering some issue after I deploy my application to railway. I encounter JwtTokenMissingException claiming that no jwt token is found in my request header even on my landing page though I did not set the requirement for jwt authentication on the landing page. I set up the code such that requests hitting the server matching url /api/public/ can access without any authentication. Even if I add url "/", it doesnt work.

When I ng build Angular, it generates index.html file and visual studio code flagged out an error in the line onload="this.media='all'" claiming expression required. So I changed it manually to onload="this.media='all';". But I dont think this is the issue. Either way also did not resolve the issue that I am facing.

Everything works well in local environment with the same code but not in production. Thus, I am seeking help to find out what is the issue.

My railway domain is https://tfipminiproject-production.up.railway.app/

The following codes below show snippets of the error I encounter in my deploy log and also snippets of my code which might be causing the issue.
Hope to seek all your help! Thank you!

```
Snippets of Error in Deploy Log:
ERROR 1 --- [nio-7055-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: miniProject.server.exception.JwtTokenMissingException: No JWT token found in the request headers] with root cause
﻿miniProject.server.exception.JwtTokenMissingException: No JWT token found in the request headers
﻿at miniProject.server.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:43) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
﻿at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
﻿at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar!/:6.1.0]
﻿at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar!/:6.1.0]
﻿at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar!/:6.1.0]
﻿at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar!/:6.1.0]
﻿at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar!/:6.1.0]
﻿at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar!/:6.1.0]
```

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
   
   @Autowired
private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
 
@Autowired
private UserAuthService userAuthService;
 
   @Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
throws ServletException, IOException {
 
String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
 
if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer")) {
throw new JwtTokenMissingException("No JWT token found in the request headers");
}
 
String token = header.substring(7);
 
// Optional - verification
jwtUtil.validateToken(token);
 
UserVo userVo = jwtUtil.getUserDataFromToken(token);
 
UserDetails userDetails = userAuthService.loadUserByUsername(userVo.getUsername());
 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
 
       //create an Authentication object with the AuthenticationToken
usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
 
if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
}
 
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
   
   @Autowired
private UserAuthService userAuthService;
 
   @Autowired
private ApiAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
 
   @Bean
   public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
       return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
   }
 
   @Bean
   public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
   return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/api/public/**");
   }
 
 
   @Bean
   public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
     DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      
     authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userAuthService);
     authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  
     return authProvider;
   }
 
 
    @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
       .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint))
       .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
       .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
       .anyRequest().authenticated());
 
       http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
       
       http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(),   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
       return http.build();
   }
 
       @Bean
public RegistrationBean jwtAuthFilterRegister(JwtAuthenticationFilter filter) {
FilterRegistrationBean<JwtAuthenticationFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
return registrationBean;
}
 
 
   @Bean
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception {
       return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
   }
 
   @Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

Comment: using jwt tokens as sessions is very insecure.